# what is `_ArrayBuffer` in Swift and how and when I should to use it?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

When debugging a crash with crash message `Thread 1: Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`. I passing a list to a function: `[MyObject]` but the debugger in debug window area of Xcode show me:

```
list([Project.MyObject])
  _buffer (_ArrayBuffer<Project.MyObject>)
     _storage(_ArrayBridgeStorage)
       rawValue = (Bultin.BridgeObject)
```

**Update:**
Instate of create and passing list of `MyObject` from `XCTestCase` class. I move the method which create list of `MyObject` into my logic class. The test is `Success`. So I am sure the crash relate to cocoa bug. But still don't know how to work around to fix it.

Comment: Just make sure your `NSArray` only contains `MyObject` types

Answer (score 0):

The crash has nothing to do with what `_ArrayBuffer` is. The crash is because you obtained an NSArray from Cocoa / Objective-C where an array of MyObject was expected, and something in the NSArray was *not* a MyObject.

That does happen now and again, mostly because of bugs in Cocoa itself. (I give an example here: [UIDynamicAnimator items(in:) crashes in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774897/uidynamicanimator-itemsin-crashes-in-ios-11).) Unfortunately you showed no code of yours at all, so how it happened in your case is anyone's guess.

Comment: Hi , i am facing specialized _ArrayBuffer._getElementSlowPath(Int) issue in some of device (mostly in iOS 11 and some of 10.0) randomly (Happened sometimes). My project is with swift 3.0 and i'm using firebase crashlytics with pods. Does my problems also related to cocoa itself. Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation   0x18a74a1c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib     0x18918455c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation    0x18a6b53dc __CFArrayGetCallBacks
3  USU ACCESS    0x10017174c specialized _ArrayBuffer._getElementSlowPath(Int) -> AnyObject (CalendarView.swift)

Comment: Using Xcode 8.3.3 (swift 3.0). Is it related to this ? Do i must need upgrade Xcode and swift version to get rid off this ?